# Open XML SDK 2.0 to get access to excel 2010 worksheet by name

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, excel-2010

I have an Excel 2010 spreadsheet that has 3 worksheets named Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3.

I'm trying to get a reference to a worksheet by name.

I'm using the code:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myWorkbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FileName, true))
{
    //Access the main Workbook part, which contains all references 
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = myWorkbook.WorkbookPart;

    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.Last(); 

    // this gives me Sheet1
    SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
}
```

I am trying to get a reference to Sheet2, but I cannot find a way to do this.

I'm getting closer, but I'm not there yet:

```
var x = workbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Where(s=> s.GetAttribute("name", "").Value == "Sheet2").FirstOrDefault();
```

That gets me a reference to the sheet, but not to the data on the sheet

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What you really want is the `WorksheetPart` which is what contains the `SheetData` that you are looking for.  Grabbing the `Sheets` under the `Workbook` will only give you certain metadata about the worksheets.  Here is an example on how to grab that `WorksheetPart` (feel free to add error checking as you see fit as I assume the `sheetName` already exists by calling `First` and not `FirstOrDefault`)

```
public WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPart(WorkbookPart workbookPart, string sheetName)
{
    string relId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => sheetName.Equals(s.Name)).Id;
    return (WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relId);
}
```

Then just use your code above to grab the correct SheetData reference and you will be able to find the data you want from there.

Answer (score 7):

Here is some code to process a spreadsheet with a specific tab or sheet name and dump it to something like CSV.  (I chose a pipe instead of comma).

I wish it was easier to get the value from a cell, but I think this is what we are stuck with.  You can see that I reference the MSDN documents where I got most of this code.  That is what Microsoft recommends.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Got code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx
    /// </summary>
    [Test]
    public void WriteOutExcelFile()
    {
        var fileName = "ExcelFiles\\File_With_Many_Tabs.xlsx";
        var sheetName = "Submission Form"; // Existing tab name.
        using (var document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, isEditable: false))
        {
            var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
            var sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
            var worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)(workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id));
            var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

            foreach (var row in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
            {
                foreach (var cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                {
                    Console.Write("|" + GetCellValue(cell, workbookPart));
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Got code from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cell"></param>
    /// <param name="workbookPart"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetCellValue(Cell cell, WorkbookPart workbookPart)
    {
        if (cell == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var value = cell.CellFormula != null
            ? cell.CellValue.InnerText 
            : cell.InnerText.Trim();

        // If the cell represents an integer number, you are done. 
        // For dates, this code returns the serialized value that 
        // represents the date. The code handles strings and 
        // Booleans individually. For shared strings, the code 
        // looks up the corresponding value in the shared string 
        // table. For Booleans, the code converts the value into 
        // the words TRUE or FALSE.
        if (cell.DataType == null)
        {
            return value;
        }
        switch (cell.DataType.Value)
        {
            case CellValues.SharedString:

                // For shared strings, look up the value in the
                // shared strings table.
                var stringTable =
                    workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                // If the shared string table is missing, something 
                // is wrong. Return the index that is in
                // the cell. Otherwise, look up the correct text in 
                // the table.
                if (stringTable != null)
                {
                    value =
                        stringTable.SharedStringTable
                            .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                }
                break;

            case CellValues.Boolean:
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "0":
                        value = "FALSE";
                        break;
                    default:
                        value = "TRUE";
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
```